# why is energy not required for the first step in the TCA?

Tags: biochemistry

I find biochemistry challenging since the basics aren't very well explained, such as why some reactions require energy while others do not. One of the constants I've been able to find is that energy (and large amounts of it) seem to be gained from oxidizing an aldehyde group to a karboxyl group (like the conversion of fructose 1,6-biphosphate to glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate), or a hydroxyl group to a keto group (like when hydroxyethyl-TPP reacts with lipimine and forms acetollipoamide). I rationalize this by thinking carbon must gain more from losing four electrons than from gaining them, hence the reactivity of methane and the non-reactivity of carbon dioxide.

But this does not seem to be constant. In the first step in the citric acid cycle (when oxaloacetate and Acetyl Coenzyme A react to form citrate) the keto group of oxoloacetate actually turn into a hydroxyl group.

If energy is gained by turning a hydroxyl group into a keto group then energy should be *consumed* while doing the reverse. Why isn't this the case when Oxoloacetate and Acetyl Coenzyme A react to form citrate? Shouldn't this step require the expenditure of ATP?

If the fault lies with my underlying theory then please say so and point me towards a better model!

Comment: Not sure about the specifics, but in any reaction, you need to carefully consider all reactants and all products. The textbook depiction of the citric acid cycle focuses on the main intermediates (pyruvate onwards), but there are other things that react and are formed (NADH, CO2, etc.) and all of these come with associated energy changes / conributions to the reaction enthalpy. To really understand the reaction, though, you will probably need to dive into the mechanism.

Comment: A lot of the “energy” for that step comes from the hydrolysis of the CoA ester to a free acid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although your reasoning isn't quite correct, it is true that simply forming citrate from acetate and oxaloacetate is not an energetically favorable reaction under standard biological conditions. What you've overlooked, however, is that after the C-C bond formation reaction occurs, the CoA ester is hydrolyzed to a carboxylic acid, which immediately ionizes to a carboxylate. This hydrolysis and ionization is very energetically favorable, making the overall reaction much more favorable.

You can say, therefore, that the energy of the reaction comes from the earlier investment in converting acetate to acetyl-CoA, which is achieved via net hydrolysis of an ATP molecule to phosphate and ADP, a reaction which is well known to be energetically favorable.